# Turning a dynamic MySQL pivot query into a view

Tags: c#, mysql, reporting

For background information: I'm planning to do some reporting in C# with Entity Framework and I need to create a view for each report (at least I believe I do).

I have already found solutions on how to receive the information I need on [various pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns). Google was of much help, too.

However what I didn't find is how to turn this procedure into a view or something I can use for reporting.

This is my code:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(IF(r.HoursMonth = ''',
            HoursMonth,
            ''', r.SumOfHoursWorked, NULL)) AS ''',
            HoursMonth, ''''
            )
    ) INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT HoursMonth, SumOfHoursWorked FROM report_HoursPerMonthPerEmployerCode ORDER BY HoursMonth) AS t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT e.employerName, ', @sql, ' FROM employer AS e LEFT JOIN report_HoursPerMonthPerEmployerName AS r on e.employerName = r.employerName GROUP BY employerName');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Try adding `create or replace view v_name as ` before the `select`.

Comment: Wow, that was easier than expected. However, I need to refresh this every time I get new columns, correct?